# How to decide to create a content type or two if there are both common and uncommon fields?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type that has about **80** fields.

It has a select list field at top and there are two options: `Yes` or `No`.

If **Yes** is selected all the 80 fields are used and if the **No** is selected, the last 30 fields are not used. For both two options, 50 fields are **common**.

I wonder, if I should go for creating **two content types** for this structure, or if continuing  with "**one**" (only) is better. If I continue with this "one" content type, 30 fields will be empty for the "No" options and can it be a "bad" thing for the database (waste of space etc.)?

*(If I continue with one content type I will use some modules such as [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) etc).*

### Is there anybody faced with a similar situation and is there a "better" way?

*(Additional information: this content type is used for an academic resource. If the resource is in English I will only fill the 50 fields. If the resource is in another language I will fill the 50 fields and also fill the other 30 fields.)*

Comment: How do those 55 fields differ? I don't know what you mean by international notation.

Comment: @NiallMurphy you're right, it was a bit unclear. I think it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use only 1 content type, and use the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module to hide those 30 extra fields for your select list field with value **No**.

This excerpt from this module's project page seems to perfectly fit as a possible solution for this approach:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.

## Possible alternative

True, you might also go for 2 content types instead. But in that case you're using an approach as described in the (illuminating, I think) article "[Relativity model for Drupal](http://jay-epstein.com/relativity/overview)". For more details on that, and the typical modules involved in that approach, refer to my answer to "[How do I model content (types) from a database-centric point of view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156626/how-do-i-model-content-types-from-a-database-centric-point-of-view/156627#156627)".

In the long run, I bet the overall implementation of your entire site would be much better (eg: you'd need way less contributed modules). But that also implies you're willing to do a way higher effort/investment then just adding the Conditional Fields module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and especially for the link. It was really a very interesting reading for me.